# Display IRC Chat in TextView with galde, gtk3 and python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, gtk, irc, glade

This is my first try in building a gui and im trying to set up an irc client on ubuntu 14.04. Actually i got stuck when i tried to output the chat data in a textview on the gui but i think im missing something important here. 
I was already able to send the chat data into the textview, when i put a while-loop into the button_clicked event. But then the whole gui of course hang up. So either the Chat read function reads only once or always. At least i tried to rearrange the structure around the Gtk.main() and it lead me to a "maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp" error. it might have something to do with the setup of def **init**().

Maybe you could have a look at my code.
best regards,
yoshiwob

**uimain.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk
import botmain
from botmain import connect, message, disconnect, read_chat, userlist 
import os

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Builder().add_from_file("gladeui/uimain.glade")
        Gtk.Builder().connect_signals(Gui())
        window = Gtk.Builder().get_object("window1")
        window.show_all()

    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def on_BTexit_clicked(self, button):
        os._exit(0)

    def on_BTconnect_clicked(self, button):
        if button.get_label() == 'Connect':
            button.set_label('Disonnect')
            connected = True   
            connect()
#             twitch_userlist()
        else:
            button.set_label('Connect')
            disconnect()
            connected = False

    def on_BTsend_clicked(self, entry):
        message(entry.get_text())

def main():
    read_chat(builder)
    Gtk.main_iteration_do(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gui()
    main();
```

**botmain.py**

```
import socket #imports module allowing connection to IRC
import threading #imports module allowing timing functions
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gnome_sudoku import gtk_goodies
import time

#sets variables for connection to twitch chat
bot_owner = 'deryoshiii'
nick = '-nick-' 
channel = '#-nick-'
server = 'irc.twitch.tv'
password = '-oauth-'
irc = socket.socket()
queue = 13 #sets variable for anti-spam queue functionality
connected = False

def connect():  
    print("Connecting...")
    irc.settimeout(300)
    irc.connect((server, 6667)) #connects to the server

    #sends variables for connection to twitch chat
    irc.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
    irc.send('USER ' + nick + ' 0 * :' + bot_owner + '\r\n')
    irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
    irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')
    print("Connected")

def userlist():
    print('getting userlist...')
    irc.send('WHO %s' % channel)

#http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18292-Python-PyQt-IRC-Client
def disconnect(): 
    irc.send('QUIT :')
#     irc.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
#     irc.close()

def message(msg): #function for sending messages to the IRC chat
    global queue
    queue = 5
    #print queue
    if queue < 20: #ensures does not send >20 msgs per 30 seconds.
        irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + msg + '\r\n')
    else:
        print('Message deleted')

def queuetimer(): #function for resetting the queue every 30 seconds
    global queue
    #print 'queue reset'
    queue = 0
    threading.Timer(30,queuetimer).start()
    queuetimer()
```